# No actualiza bien los datos de mi jqxKnob

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

Necesito ayuda con un fragmento de código. Estoy haciendo unas gráficas con jqxwidgets.

Mi reporte cuenta con dos filtros: uno es por fechas, que es fecha inicial y fecha final, y el segundo es por departamento.

Cuando hago la primera consulta todos mis resultados salen bien, pero cuando no actualizo la página y hago otra consulta me pone el dato máximo en una sola gráfica, pero todas las demás graficas si actualizan bien.

Ya intenté con destroy, y cuando hago esta segunda consulta me destruye la gráfica y no la vuelve a mostrar.

codigo:

```
$('#Hostigamiento_kn').jqxKnob({
                        height: 200, 
                        width: 200,
                        value: datos.CATEGORIA_M.REGISTROS,
                        min: 0,
                        max: datos.CATEGORIA_M.MAXIMO,
                        allowValueChangeOnMouseWheel: false,
                        startAngle: 270,
                        endAngle: 630,
                        rotation: 'clockwise',
                        style: { fill: "#fff" },
                        dial: {
                            style: {
                                fill: "#fff"
                            },
                            innerRadius: '68%',
                            outerRadius: '92%',
                            startAngle: 0,
                            endAngle: 360
                        },
                        progressBar: {
                            style: { fill: '#00a644' },
                            background: {fill: '#eeeeee'},
                            size: '30%',
                            offset: '70%'
                        },
                        pointer:
                            {
                                type: 'line',
                                style: { fill: '#00a644' },
                                size: '30%',
                                offset: '70%',
                                thickness: 20
                            }
                    });
                    var input = $('<input class="inputKnob" disabled>');
                    $('#Hostigamiento_kn').append(input);
                    input.val($('#Hostigamiento_kn').val());
                    $(input).on('mousedown', function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    });
                    $(input).on('keyup', function () {
                        var val = $(this).val();
                        $('#Hostigamiento_kn').val(val);
                    });
                    $('#Hostigamiento_kn').on('change', function (event) {
                        if (event.target.nodeName == "INPUT")
                            return;
                        if (event.args.changeSource == 'propertyChange' || event.args.changeSource == 'val') { return; }
                        $(input).val(event.args.value);
                    })
```